# MySQL replication, auto_increment and rollbacks

Tags: mysql, transactions, replication, auto-increment

I have a bunch of scripts that perform transactional "simulations" against a MySQL slave replicant, which are then rolled back. These simulations are performed against the slave, so as to not affect the performance of my master database.

I use auto_increment primary keys quite heavily throughout my schema and I'm noticing that by rolling back the transactions, some ids are being lost and as a result over time the ids in the slave do not match those of the master.

I realise that not rolling back the ids is by design, but could we not say temporarily disable that feature (along with replication) while the simulations run, and then turn the feature back on (along with replication).

Or is there a better way of safely performing transactions on a real time copy of a MySQL database?

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea to begin with and very fragile with regards to maintaining your replication.  I would question whether you really need to perform these simulations again live replicate production data or whether it could be done against a separate DB that is created from a backup.

Comment: Yes, these simulations need to be against live data, as they will be used to drive key decisions from within my platform. This replicant would only be used for these simulations, so I'm not concerned with any knock on effect for other apps.

Comment: OK.  Do you have the possibility to halt slave SQL thread during execution of your simulations?  This may make it to where you don't have such problems with unique ID's.